# Copy excel data to uitable using push button and popupmenu

Tags: matlab-guide

I am new to Matlab. I have two push button, two popup menu and one uitable in the same gui window. One push button is for importing the data from excel sheet, and updating the column names in the popup menu and another is for pasting the selected column data to uitable by using popup menu.

I have done the importing the data gui and updated column names in the popup menu. I can't able to paste the data in uitable by selecting respective columns.

Kindly help me in this regards, my code is given below,

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbuttonLoadData.
function pushbuttonLoadData_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbuttonLoadData (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
filename=uigetfile({'*.xls';'*.csv'});
handles.filename=filename;
guidata(hObject, handles);
setpopupmenuString(handles.popupmenuA,eventdata,handles)
setpopupmenuString(handles.popupmenuB,eventdata,handles)
set(handles.popupmenuA,'callback','mainGui(''updateUitable'',hObject,eventdata,g    uidata(hObject)')
set(handles.popupmenuB,'callback','mainGui(''updateUitable'',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)')

function setpopupmenuString(hObject,eventdata,handles)
filename=handles.filename;
[numbers,colNames]=xlsread(filename);
set(hObject, 'String', colNames(1,:) );
class(colNames)
size(colNames)
colNames{1,1}

function [x,y] = readExcelcolumns(filename, xColNum,yColNum)
a = xlsread(filename);
x = a (:, xColNum);
y = a (:, yColNum);
[x,y] = readExcelcolumns(filename, xColNum,yColNum)
xColNum(:,2)=importdata('-pastespecial');
yColNum(:,3)=importdata('-pastespecial');

function pushbuttonApply_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbuttonApply (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
data = handles.filename;
set(handles.uitable1,'Value',xColNum, yColNum);'
```

Comment: Please read the documentation for the functionality you're trying to use. `Value` is not a property of a [`uitable` object](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html). You want to set the [`Data` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable-properties.html#property_data).

Comment: I tried, could you please correct the code. Also suggest me is any other possible way to do this